# nhibernate transaction deadlock issue

Tags: nhibernate

I am currently facing transaction deadlock issues in Nhibernate data layer. The scenario is :

I have a large transaction table T1. This table undergoes frequent write/update operations. Also, a service frequently reads this table(based on filter) and merges the data with client cache(on client machine). The frequency of read is very high.

At times (does not follow pattern) , the deadlock issue surfaces.

How can I trace this issue?(I have dbo role). Is there any Nhibernate setting that can help in this context?

Answer (score 1):

As your service only reads the table, you could change your application to use an optimistic lock approach.

More about optimistic locking with NH: http://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=5&ved=0CDMQFjAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fknol.google.com%2Fk%2Ffabio-maulo%2Fnhibernate-chapter-5-basic-o-r-mapping%2F1nr4enxv3dpeq%2F8&ei=biB9TLjMNIL88AbQ4smNBw&usg=AFQjCNHpZ80cpxa6IqzxILfQU9XACQjbYA&sig2=md9f4mYYnvFPowB-RZbuag.

Filipe

Comment: Linking to answers outside of SO. is bad. Such as this is now a dead link.